# Multiple DbContexts but only one is running when using Azure DevOps to deploy

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-devops

I have an API with multiple DbContexts (each with a separate schema) that all exist in the same database with the same connection string. One API has "dbo", the default, and the other is "template". When deploying, only the dbo tables are created, no template schema tables are made. I notice though that the schema "template" does not exists in the Security->Schemas section of the database.

There are no errors from Azure DevOps and no logging that shows anything.

I can run `update-database -ConfigurationTypeName Configuration` and `update-database -ConfigurationTypeName TemplateConfig` with no problems locally.

The context for the normal configuration is:

```cs
namespace Acme.DAL.Contexts
{
    public class TemplateDbContext : BaseDbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

        public TemplateDbContext() : base(ConnectionString)
        {
            SchemaName = "template";
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TemplateDbContext, TemplateConfig>());
        }
        public TemplateDbContext(string connString) : base(connString)
        {
            SchemaName = "template";
        }
    }
}
```

BaseDbContext is just

```cs
namespace Acme.DAL.Contexts
{
    public abstract class BaseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected const string ConnectionString = "AcmeContext";
        protected string SchemaName;

        protected BaseDbContext() : base(ConnectionString) {}

        protected BaseDbContext(string connString) : base(connString) {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            if (SchemaName != null)
            {
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);
            }
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration files are:

#### Template (not working)

```cs
namespace Acme.DAL.Migrations.Templates
{
    public class TemplateConfig : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TemplateDbContext>
    {
        public TemplateConfig()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            CommandTimeout = 300;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\Templates";
        }
        protected override void Seed(TemplateDbContext context)
        {
            context.TemplateWorkshops.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, SeedTemplates.GetTemplates().ToArray());
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

#### dbo migrations

```cs
namespace Acme.DAL.Migrations
{
    public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Contexts.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;

            CommandTimeout = 300;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Contexts.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, SeedClients.GetDefaultClients().ToArray());

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Shout if anything else is needed.

I checked if the connection string had been mutated by the time it got to the published web API but it hadn't, it's still correct.

I expected that this would work given that running `update-database` locally works.

Comment: Is "Contexts.ApplicationDbContext" also a subclass of "BaseDbContext"?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind: Are you sure that TemplateContext gets constructed? Is it ever called? Automatic migrations kick only in, when you actually use the context. And how are you initializing the TemplateContext? You only set the initializer when called without argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was this was that something was breaking before I ever hit part of the site that would result in the `setInitializer` method being called for the TemplateDbContext. Therefore no tables were constructed (as per [Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8019420/flex)'s comment (don't know how to tag you with credit as it was a comment)).

The code itself above is ok.